# TabAnimationActivity is not an enclosing class

Tags: android

i get  this error :    TabAnimationActivity is not an enclosing class

when i call intent :

```
case R.id.action_switch:
            Intent intent = new Intent(TabAnimationActivity.this, TabsHeaderActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: im new in this domain, i just tried to see some codes and understanding it ..thank you for any help

Comment: Can you please post the entire class where the code is in?

Comment: thank you  but the code is too long , wich part o f the code

Comment: the entire code of the class please

Comment: edit your post and put there your class

Comment: If you can't, just tell me the name of the class please

Comment: i tried to copy it but the numbers of caracteres is limited...by the way i resolved it , my classe is TabActivity that's why  the intent was not working .. i changed it : Intent intent=new Intent(TabActivity.this,.......) thank you so much  and have a good day

Comment: your are wellcome!

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of TabAnimationActivity.this. You have to pass the current object of the activity.

The `new Intent` requires the *current activity's context* (first param) and the *class which you want to initializate* (second param).